# Managing Wordpress Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

A Wordpress theme has following components:

- theme.zip file
- demo-content.xml
- PSD.zip file (contains files such as icon-blog.psd, icon-home.psd, integrity-blog.psd, ... renew-home.psd)

Using WP Admin (WP Backend) I have managed to upload theme.zip file.
Using WP Importer I have managed to upload demo content.
However, what do I do with PSD files?
I would like to add that the current frontend looks very basic. And I assume PSD files serve to enrich frontend. But how do I use them? Where do I "import" them? How do I do it?

Comment: You probably want to ask this question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thx
didn't know about that page

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the comments, I have to say that if the tag exists, the answer should be answered here too.

Your .PSD is basically all the images that compose your theme in one editable file.
The extension of the file is meant to be opened with Photoshop and if you open it there, you should see the design of your theme ready to be cut and applied into HTML and CSS.

For Wordpress or your site it has no utility by itself, however, if you want to change some button, icon  or related it's just a matter of open the editable, change it, save the image and replace it on the server.

Ex:

You bought a theme initially developed in English and you have a button which is an image that says "Register". Since it's not editable, there's no code change that can help you, so the only way you have is to open the .PSD, edit the button and save it again as image, replacing the old one.